# Excusing oneself

Tags: idioms

What’s the actual meaning of the expression “I will excuse myself ”?

I’ve thought of it as kind of a joking expression about doing something that would actually require the excuse of someone else in a more formal situation, but I figure that need not actually be the case.

Comment: Please could you supply more context? Perhaps an example dialogue where the phrase is used?

Comment: The most obvious use I can think of is when one is leaving a group, or in the middle of a conversation.

Comment: That particular phrasing always makes me think you are removing yourself from a contentious situation or discussion in a polite manner with perhaps an implication others should do so also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not meant as a joke at all.

The phrase " to excuse oneself" refers to the act of saying "Excuse me" and leaving.

> Ex. I **excused myself** and stepped out of the room.
>
> Ex. "If anyone has to leave early, please feel free to **excuse
>   yourself**."

In direct speech, it's an expression used [to be polite when you leave early](http://www.goenglish.com/Idioms/Excuse+Yourself.asp).

> Ex. "I'm not feeling so good today so **I'll** (have to) **excuse
>   myself** from the meeting."

Comment: Exactly. OED sense 7b ***to excuse oneself** - to ask permission or apologize before leaving.*

Comment: I think the OP's wondering about "Excuse me" vs. "I will excuse myself."

Comment: I think OP just isn't a native speaker, so he thinks the reflexive form is odd. Of course it's not - though it's [far more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+must+excuse+myself%2CI+will+excuse+myself&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to say *"I **must** excuse myself"*, rather than *"I **will** excuse myself"*. Note that there's no special meaning implied by *"will"* over *"must"*, in that context.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing joking in this. *Excuse* being transitive, takes two persons.

The one being 'excused' is 'myself' here. The one excusing is the person being addressed.

One can read this as: 'If you may so permit, I will consider myself excused (by you).'

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. Doesn't the reflexivity of "myself" mean that it is me who is doing the excusing, rather than the person being addressed? I mean, even without the reflexivity, the subject is explicitly "I".

Comment: @Dolda2000 No, it is not reflexive, it is transitive.

Comment: "Excuse" might be transitive, but "myself" is reflexive.

Comment: @Dolda2000 'Myself' being not a verb, it cannot be reflexive or transitive. You need to think a bit harder: "I will do it myself." does not mean anything reflexive, but just that the "I" is stressed. On the other hand, "I will reward myself." would have a reflexive implication on the verb 'reward'.

Comment: @Kris How is "I excuse myself" different in construction or analysis from "I reward myself"?

Answer (score 3):

When you ask someone to excuse you as you leave a group or in the middle of a conversation, you're asking the other person or people ["to give [you] permission to leave; to release [you]"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/excuse). (Definition 5.)

Comment: Is that in someway different from my answer, just for clarification?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that usually, if you are leaving a group, you seek the permission of the others in the group first.  Obviously, this is just a polite fiction; you aren't *really* asking their permission, just giving them the opportunity to say goodbye or make any other parting remarks.  You do, however, typically say, "Excuse me" or "If you'll excuse me" or something like that.

If the group is large, for each departing person to go through this routine is more disruptive than it's worth.  Therefore a person "excuses himself": he doesn't even pretend to seek permission, and just slips away.

Therefore, actually saying "I will excuse myself" when you're in a group of only two or three is slightly aggressive.  You're hinting that you're bored or uncomfortable or have some other practical reason for not choosing the more polite exit.